# Oracle SQL: Update a column from select

Tags: mysql, oracle, sql-update

I have to update `SRCFILE_FULL_COUNT_HIGH`. Set new value from `NOVA_HODNOTA`. Here is working select.
Thank you!

```
UPDATE SRCFILE_ID, NOVA_HODNOTA, SRCFILE_FULL_COUNT_HIGH as STARA_HODNOTA
from 
(
```

working select:

```
 SELECT /*+ no_index(rh FILEINS_STATUS_FK_I) */
 rh.SRCFILE_ID, rh.FILEINS_RECORD_COUNT, rh.FILEINS_EFFECTIVE_DATE,       esf.SRCFILE_FULL_COUNT_HIGH,
 100*(rh.FILEINS_RECORD_COUNT/esf.SRCFILE_FULL_COUNT_HIGH) as PROCENTA,
 CASE 
 WHEN (100*(rh.FILEINS_RECORD_COUNT/esf.SRCFILE_FULL_COUNT_HIGH)) >= 80 
 THEN FILEINS_RECORD_COUNT*1.25 
 ELSE SRCFILE_FULL_COUNT_HIGH 
 END AS NOVA_HODNOTA
 FROM ETL_SOURCE_FILE_INST rh,
 (SELECT MAX(FILEINS_EFFECTIVE_DATE) AS maxdate, SRCFILE_ID
  FROM ETL_SOURCE_FILE_INST
  GROUP BY SRCFILE_ID) maxresults,
 ETL_SOURCE_FILES esf
 WHERE rh.SRCFILE_ID = maxresults.SRCFILE_ID
 and rh.SRCFILE_ID = esf.SRCFILE_ID
 AND rh.FILEINS_EFFECTIVE_DATE= maxresults.maxdate
 AND RH.FILEINS_INCREMENTAL_FLAG = 'F'
 and ESF.SRCFILE_FULL_COUNT_FLAG = 'Y'
 and RH.FILEINS_STATUS = 'COMPLETE'
 ORDER BY SRCFILE_ID ASC
```

END of select

```
)
WHERE STARA_HODNOTA = SRCFILE_FULL_COUNT_HIGH
SET STARA_HODNOTA = NOVA_HODNOTA
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
merge into
  ETL_SOURCE_FILE_INST i
using
  (
    SELECT /*+ no_index(rh FILEINS_STATUS_FK_I) */
rh.SRCFILE_ID, rh.FILEINS_RECORD_COUNT, rh.FILEINS_EFFECTIVE_DATE,       esf.SRCFILE_FULL_COUNT_HIGH,
100*(rh.FILEINS_RECORD_COUNT/esf.SRCFILE_FULL_COUNT_HIGH) as PROCENTA,
CASE 
WHEN (100*(rh.FILEINS_RECORD_COUNT/esf.SRCFILE_FULL_COUNT_HIGH)) >= 80 
THEN FILEINS_RECORD_COUNT*1.25 
ELSE SRCFILE_FULL_COUNT_HIGH 
END AS NOVA_HODNOTA
FROM ETL_SOURCE_FILE_INST rh,
(SELECT MAX(FILEINS_EFFECTIVE_DATE) AS maxdate, SRCFILE_ID
FROM ETL_SOURCE_FILE_INST
GROUP BY SRCFILE_ID) maxresults,
ETL_SOURCE_FILES esf
WHERE rh.SRCFILE_ID = maxresults.SRCFILE_ID
and rh.SRCFILE_ID = esf.SRCFILE_ID
AND rh.FILEINS_EFFECTIVE_DATE= maxresults.maxdate
AND RH.FILEINS_INCREMENTAL_FLAG = 'F'
and ESF.SRCFILE_FULL_COUNT_FLAG = 'Y'
and RH.FILEINS_STATUS = 'COMPLETE'
  ) t on (t.SRCFILE_ID = i.SRCFILE_ID)
when matched then
update
set
  i.SRCFILE_FULL_COUNT_HIGH = t.NOVA_HODNOTA
where
  i.SRCFILE_FULL_COUNT_HIGH = t.SRCFILE_FULL_COUNT_HIGH
;
```